# Can I manufacture my device in view of US 1300137?

Tags: us1300137

I am trying to sell a letterboard online and I would like to know if my metal bar for hanging the letterboard would violate this patent. Mine is a letterboard and this is a picture frame so I want to be in the clear.

Answer (score 2):

This patent issued on 8 April 1919. At that time, patents lasted for 17 years from grant. This patent therefore expired in 1936 (if not earlier).

It is therefore well expired, and will therefore not be a problem for you: you could freely copy it if you wanted.